Can not use sched_setaffinity() on macOS
code detail
error output
Xcode-version
xcode-select version 2409.
gcc version:
Apple clang version 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.3)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin24.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
I can not find a solution on net...or maybe I missed something?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Please write down your source code and do not post it as an image.

Tim, I'm surprised you didn't see (well, cite) this.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

See: http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/processor_assign.html

I will bear it in mind that do not upload images about code. thx

The Linux manual specifies the following in the CONFORMING TO section:

These system calls are Linux-specific.

Under Linux/GLIBC pthread library makes available the non-posix pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(). Try it to see if your MacOS C library offers the same...
